# Subset of a set that is in another set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we have a set, say

$$ A = \{\emptyset, X \} $$

and we know that $B \subset X$, does that imply $B \subset A$?

Comment: No, in exactly the same way that $x\in X$ does not imply that $x\in A$.  $A$ only contains two elements $\emptyset$ and $X$.  That these elements are sets themselves is irrelevant.  The *only* subsets of $A$ are then $\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{X\}$ and $\{\emptyset,X\}$.

Comment: No.  For example, set $X=\{1, 2, 3\}$ and $B=\{2, 3\}$. Then clearly $B \subset X$, but it isn't true that $B \subset A$ because the only two elements of $A$ are $\varnothing$ and $X$, and neither is $B$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Why are you posting a perfectly good answer as a comment?

Comment: No, in computer language terms that would be a type error.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer -

No, it doesn't.

---

## A Definition -

- Subset -  A set, $\mathbb{Y}$ is said to be a subset of another set, $\mathbb{Z}$, ( denoted as $\mathbb{Y} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ ) iff, $\forall x\in \mathbb{Y}$, $x\in \mathbb{Z}$.

---

## Illustrative example -

Let, $\mathbb{X}=\{ 1,2\} $ and $\mathbb{B}={1}$.

Now, note that $\mathbb{B}$ is clearly a subset of $\mathbb{X}$.

But, $\mathbb{A} := \{ \phi, \{ 1,2 \} \} = \{\{\},\{1,2\}\}$. Clearly, $1\in \mathbb{B}$, but $1\not \in \mathbb{A} $. Thus, $\mathbb{B}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{A}$.

---

## General Explanation -

Here, your set $\mathbb{B}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{X}$. Now, if $\mathbb{X}$ were to be a subset of $\mathbb{A}$, then $\mathbb{B}$ would clearly be a subset of $\mathbb{A}$, I.e.$\mathbb{B} \subset \mathbb{X}$ and $\mathbb{X} \subset \mathbb{A} \Rightarrow \mathbb{B} \subset \mathbb{A}$.

But here, $\mathbb{X} $ is merely an element of $\mathbb{A}$. This means that the elements of $\mathbb{X}$ are ***not*** *elements* of $\mathbb{A}$ but are elements of a set which is an element of $\mathbb{A}$.

Similarly, since $ \mathbb{B} \subset \mathbb{X} $, we have the fact that it's elements are also not elements of $\mathbb{A}$.

Thus, $\mathbb{B}$ is not subset of $\mathbb{A}$.

**Another way of seeing this** is that whenever we have some set, say $\mathbb{A}=\{ a,b\} $, only it's *immediate* 'comma-seperated' members are considered to be it's elements (by definition). So, in this case, $a$ and $b$ are elements of $\mathbb{A}$. However, even if $a$ is also a set, it's element(s) do not automatically become elements of $\mathbb{A}$ as they are not it's immediate members.